# How does one set JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition for Serilog.Sinks.Seq

Tags: c#, serialization, sequence, serilog, system.text.json

I'm using Serilog.Sinks.Seq in my C# app (see the configuration code below) but I can't figure out how to set the JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition to ignore nulls.  Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated...

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .UseSerilog((context, config) =>
    {
        var seqUri = new Uri(context.Configuration["SeqUri"]!);
        var seqApiKey = context.Configuration["SeqApiKey"]!;

        config.MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Seq(seqUri.AbsoluteUri, apiKey: seqApiKey);
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WriteTo.Seq` does not provide any ways to use `JsonSerializerOptions`. The Seq server itself is responsible for handling the serialization of the log events. It's designed to work with structured log data so it uses its own serialization format which is built for optimization. I'm not aware of anyways to modify or override it.

You can use other sinks for logging which provide support for custom serialization `Serilog.Sinks.File` or `Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch`. You can use these sinks to log and then use `Log Shipping` to consume those logs in `Seq`.

Comment: I was afraid that'd be the case.  Thankfully, my ask was a nice-to-have, but not crucial